# Tensorflow training loss extremely low from the start of training

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets

I am working on the kaggle galaxy zoo classification problem, and I am getting a weird result.

I am training a CNN to classify between smooth and featured galaxies. Lots of the measures seem to be reasonable, the accuracy, f1 score, AUC of the ROC curve, and so on. However, when I look at the loss, the training loss is extremely low (loss: 4.4123e-05 after the first epoch). The validation loss seems more reasonable (val loss: 0.2952 after the first epoch).

I don't think this is an issue with overfitting because even at the very start of the first epoch–like when the first batch is training–the loss is already extremely low, but maybe the model is too complicated. I am worried that the notebook is somehow saving a memory of the weights, but I recompile the model each time, so I am unsure how that could be the case.

here is the code for my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the CNN architecture with dropout
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),  # Dropout layer after the first convolutional layer
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),  # Dropout layer after the second convolutional layer
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),  # Dropout layer after the third convolutional layer
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(380, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),  # Dropout layer after the first dense layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile and train the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy())

history = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=40, class_weight={0: 1/n_smooth, 1: 1/n_feat})

model.save("saved_models/binary_11jun_0")
```

The data is in a tensorflow data format, and nsmooth/ nfeat were calculated above this using the training set (80, 20 split was used for training and val).
Number of instances in training set labeled class 1.1:  6587
Number of instances in training set labeled class 1.2:  12833

I have also attached images of the loss and accuracy. I believe that my validation accuracy is higher than my training accuracy at the start because of dropout, but I am unsure why the training loss is so low. Also, I realize I am overfitting around epoch 20, I just wanted to run for a long time to see if the losses would converge (they don't). I would appreciate any thoughts on the matter. Thank you![image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jake, Please share the reproducible code to replicate the issue along with the dataset you are using.